# Cakephp Table query: SUM returning 0

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm having problems when using find to sum the field num_days from table events.

```
$events = TableRegistry::get('Events');
$query = $events->find('all')
                ->select(['used' => 'sum(num_days)'])
                ->first();
```

Why `$query->used` is always 0?

`print_r($events->find('all')->select(['used' => 'sum(num_days)'])->toArray())` gives,

```
Array ( [0] => App\Model\Entity\Event Object ( [used] => 6 [[new]] => [[accessible]] => Array ( [*] => 1 ) [[dirty]] => Array ( ) [[original]] => Array ( ) [[virtual]] => Array ( ) [[errors]] => Array ( ) [[invalid]] => Array ( ) [[repository]] => Events ) )
```

6 is exactly the correct answer for the query and print_r shows it but $query->used is returning always 0.

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: @Mahesh Singh Chouhan the issue is that $query->used is not returning 6.

Comment: try `$query->order(['used' => 'DESC']);` before `$query->used`

Comment: hello... It works!! thanks, now I'm facing a new problem. This code should be placed in Event.php ( an entity for Events). but I think the code is in looping when I call $event->used in .ctp (view) file. I can't place the code in the controller because I need a where clause that will be added and will use the a field value of each entity.

Comment: i believe you can use `virtualField` in `Event.php` as `used` to fix this, also let me add above solution as answer so that it helps others too who are facing same issue

Comment: I did exactly as you suggested. Placed the code in _getUsed() { }.

Comment: ok @MaheshSinghChouhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `$query->order(['used' => 'DESC']);` before `$query->used`

Also, we can add `used` as `protected $_virtual = ['used'];` inside `Event.php` Entity File